# How do I parse a date string using DateFormat?

Tags: android, date-format, simpledateformat

I have a date string in the following format:

`Thu Oct 20 14:39:19 PST 2011`

I would like to parse it using DateFormat to get a Date object.  I'm trying it like this:

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.SHORT);
Date date = df.parse(dateString);
```

This gives a ParseException ("unparseable date").

I've also tried this:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
```

with the same results.

Is that the right `SimpleDateFormat` string?  Is there a better way to parse this date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that I was trying to parse an English date while in the French locale.

This was resolved by using this instead:

`SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.CANADA);`

Comment: @howettl: I'm glad you solved this, +1 because you accurately reported a tricky situation. I'm writing this only because no one seemed to explicitly point this out. In your original code you had dashes between the format components: **EEE-MM-dd**. That was probably the *wrong* string if your intention was to parse a date without dashes. However you tried the versions Kurtis Nusbaum and HandlerExploit suggested, without dashes *and* without explicitly passing Locale.CANADA, and it still didn't work out. So it really looks like it was a required parameter.

Answer (score 9):

Are you sure that date string is really being assigned the value `Thu Oct 20 14:39:19 PST 2011`? If that's not the problem, you could try using this code which works for me:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
public class Test{


  public static void main(String args[]){

    String toParse = "Thu Oct 20 14:39:19 PST 2011";

    String format = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy";
    SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    try{
      Date parsed = formater.parse(toParse);
    } catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried hard-coding it in my code and get the same result.

Comment: I don't know what to say.  Copying and pasting your code gives me an Unparseable date exception.

Comment: Try cleaning your build and then recompiling.

Comment: "Compiler compliance level" is set to 1.6.  Testing on a device running Android 2.1

Comment: You'd better set to 1.5, Android uses 1.6 APIs since 2.3.

Comment: Testing on a device running 2.3.3 results in the same exception.

Comment: I solved the problem.  I upvoted your answer though because you put some time into helping me.  Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the solution as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
```

Comment: I hard coded the date string instead of taking it from the database, and did a parse on the hard-coded string.  This resulted in an unparseable date exception.